# can OR be used in python pandas lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The below works

```
df['notes'] = df['notes'].apply(lambda x: x if 'Issue:' in x else "NO_ISSUE")
```

however I wanted to ask if I can do this:

```
df['notes'] = df['notes'].apply(lambda x: x if 'Issue:' or "Root Cause:" in x else "NO_ISSUE")
```

Comment: The problem isn't `or` in a lambda but that `'Issue:' or "Root Cause:" in x ` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it

```
df['notes'] = df['notes'].apply(lambda x: x if ('Issue:' in x or "Root Cause:" in x) else "NO_ISSUE")
```